# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: " " = Generic Error, unsure why

Tags: python

Why do I get this error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

with this code?

```
topscores = max(int(var[1].strip("/10\n")),int(var[2].strip("/10\n")),int(var[3].strip("/10\n")))
```

Here's the full code:

```
for filetracker in range(filecount(path)):
    filenames = glob.glob(path + "/*.txt")
    files = open(filenames[filetracker], "r")
    var = files.readlines()
    name = var[0]
    topscores = max(int(var[1].strip("/10\n")),int(var[2].strip("/10\n")),int(var[3].strip("/10\n")))
    print name + topscores
```

Comment: Would be useful to see what `var` **actually** is

Comment: and some own effort... is this your best "minimal example"?

Comment: Maybe you are trying to do something like: `int("Ryan")`

Comment: @Karoly Horvath It's the code that's the problem. If I cut it up, I couldn't be sure what the error was.

Comment: What would you expect `int('')` to be, exactly? I'd suggest reading http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @Ryan: quite the contrary. if you *don't* cut it up, and do debug prints to see what the variables are, *then* you won't know for sure what the error is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

int() is taking in strings to make numbers, however at least one of your vars must be evaluating as empty because

```
>>> int('')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    int('')
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Passing an empty string produces this error. You'll need to either check if you're getting valid strings or better yet, add a try except so you can still run the program and just note the invalid strings.

```
try:
    topscores = max(int(var[1].strip("/10\n")),int(var[2].strip("/10\n")),int(var[3].strip("/10\n")))
except ValueError:
    print ("Invalid string found in: {}".format(var))
```